# use trignometric substitution to eliminate root

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I use trig substitution to eliminate the root of $\sqrt{13 + 25x^2}$?  I know that the equation needs to be in the form $a^2 + x^2$ so that I can use $x = a\tan\theta$, but I really have no idea how to put the equation in the correct form.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, $13+25x^2=25\{\frac{13}{25}+x^2\}$   So, $a^2=\frac{13}{25}$ $\implies a=\pm \frac{\sqrt{13}}5$

Answer (score 1):

Choose

$$x=\frac{\sqrt{13}}{5} \tan{\theta}$$

Then

$$\sqrt{13+25 x^2} = \sqrt{13} \sec{\theta}$$